# Solving encryption puzzle

Tags: encryption, hash

I have this cryptography puzzle I'm stuck on, spoilers please with hints since I want to figure this out myself.

I'm given that a code in the form of x:y:z is required to access a particular goal, the example given is this:

```
alpha:2c174:Uw9BX1U=
```

And I'm meant to extrapolate Gamma. I think I've figured out how to get the middle section from the first but I'm not certain, and I have no idea how the third section relates to this in any way.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Does anyone have absolutely any ideas or hints on how this could be solved

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange - questions asking for help on crypto puzzles are actually off-topic here.